# Trigger function on React props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a function to update the user info each time a value is changed on the user page, for example when an avatar is uploaded. 
When you add an image, the image is uploaded and `props.user` is updated with the URL. I'd like to catch that `props` update and trigger the `saveUser` function.

I used the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, but `this.props` and `nextProps` are always the same, even when `props` are being updated. They seem to update at the same time although `componentWillReceiveProps` is supposed to be triggered before the `props` update.

Here is my code:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(JSON.stringify(this.props.user) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.user)){
        AuthActions.updateUser(nextProps.user); // This is never triggered
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try `componentWillUpdate`.  This way you don't have to compare props.  It'll update if the props differ from the old ones.

Comment: This does trigger the function, but I don't want it to be activated by all `props` update, only the `user` ones.

Comment: Does it get into the block?  `AuthActions.updateUser` should be `AuthActions.updateUser()` I'd think.   You might consider putting your side effect into an action so that you can get more control of when it fires.

Comment: Sorry it was a only a typo on this question, I fixed it. `updateUser` is Flux action, simply doing an API call and returning an updated user. 
What do you mean the block?
(Thank you for helping me!)

Comment: `if () {<<this is the block>>}`

Comment: No it doesn't. I logged both `nextProps` and `props` and they are the same one, updating at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155965/discussion-between-jmargolisvt-and-skaddict).